# How to move an image on the X axis?

Tags: java, android, image, axis, move

I am new in the android World!

I just would like to move an image on the x axis when I click on a button, on a simple View.

so: image.x += image.x + 1; (when I click on the button)

thank's in advance !
Lokoum.

Comment: `image.x += image.x + 1` is the same thing as `image.x = image.x + image.x + 1`. It appears you are just trying to translate by 1 unit? If so, just do `image.x++`

Comment: Yes, but how Can I display the image and move it simply ?

Comment: See this link [Link][1], Hope it will help you 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674586/how-to-move-an-imageview-over-y-axis-dynamically-using-conditions